# Как скрыть окно Tk() с помощью withdraw() и создать окно TopLevel активным(в фокусе) в Tkinter на Python 3.7?

Tags: python, tkinter, gui

Написал простую программу по авторизации пользователей, в которой создается окно ввода логина root = Tk(), далее я пытаюсь скрыть окно логина с помощью withdraw(), и создать окно ввода пароля root_admin = Toplevel(). Даже при использовании метода focus_set окно TopLevel открывается неактивным.
Подскажите, в чем проблема?

```
import win32api
from tkinter import *
global name_entry, nameuser

def root_withdraw():
    root.withdraw()

def root_admin_passw():
    l3 = Label(root_admin, text="Неправильный пароль!")
    l3.pack()

def clicked():
    global root_admin
    root_admin = Toplevel()
    root_admin.focus_set()
    l0 = Label(root_admin, text="Введите пароль", font=("Segoe UI", 18))
    l0.pack()
    pass_entry = Entry(root_admin, textvariable=passw, width=30, font=("Arial", 30, "bold"))
    pass_entry.config(show="*")
    pass_entry.focus_set()
    pass_entry.pack()
    but = Button(root_admin, font=("Arial", 18), text="Войти", command=root_admin_passw)
    but.pack()
    root_admin.update_idletasks()
    s = root_admin.geometry()
    s = s.split('+')
    s = s[0].split('x')
    width_root = int(s[0])
    height_root = int(s[1])
    w = root_admin.winfo_screenwidth()
    h = root_admin.winfo_screenheight()
    w = w // 2
    h = h // 2
    w = w - width_root // 2
    h = h - height_root // 2
    root_admin.geometry('+{}+{}'.format(w, h))
    root_admin.mainloop()

root = Tk()
win32api.LoadKeyboardLayout("00000409",1)
x = (root.winfo_screenwidth() - root.winfo_reqwidth()) / 2
y = (root.winfo_screenheight() - root.winfo_reqheight()) / 2
root.wm_geometry("+%d+%d" % (x, y))
root.title("Авторизация")

name = StringVar()
passw = StringVar()

flag_vvod_save = 0
flag_podtverzhdenie_vvod_save=0
flag_vvod_save_edit = 0
flag_ispoln = 0
flag_ispolnadm = 0
flag_enter_shk = 0
flag_sshk=0
ves=0

l0 = Label(root,text="Введите имя пользователя",font=("Segoe UI", 18))
l0.pack()
name_entry = Entry(root,textvariable=name,width=30,font=("Arial", 30, "bold"))
name_entry.focus_set()
name_entry.pack()
but = Button(root,text="Войти",font=("Arial", 18), command=lambda: [root_withdraw(), clicked()])
but.pack()

root.update_idletasks()
s = root.geometry()
s = s.split('+')
s = s[0].split('x')
width_root = int(s[0])
height_root = int(s[1])
w = root.winfo_screenwidth()
h = root.winfo_screenheight()
w = w // 2
h = h // 2
w = w - width_root // 2
h = h - height_root // 2
root.geometry('+{}+{}'.format(w, h))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Основной цикл должен быть один, в нем перерисовываются окна и обрабатываются события. Поэтому root_admin.mainloop() не нужен. Не надо два раза расчитывать координаты окон, можете получить эти данные через root.geometry(). Фокус перебрасывается на IDLE, не нашел где.

Answer (score 0):

Фокус сбрасывается при срабатывании withdraw(), помогла принудительная установка фокуса .focus_force(). Объяснение этому не нашел.

```
from tkinter import *

def root_admin_passw():
    l3['text'] = "Неправильный пароль!"


def clicked():
    global root_admin, l3

    root_admin = Toplevel()
    root_admin.wm_geometry(root.geometry())
    l0 = Label(root_admin, text="Введите пароль", font=("Segoe UI", 18))
    l0.pack()
    pass_entry = Entry(root_admin, textvariable=passw, width=30, font=("Arial", 30, "bold"))
    pass_entry.config(show="*")
    pass_entry.focus_set()
    pass_entry.pack()
    but1 = Button(root_admin, font=("Arial", 18), text="Войти", command=root_admin_passw)
    but1.pack()
    l3 = Label(root_admin, text="")
    l3.pack()

    root.withdraw()
    root_admin.focus_force()
#    root_admin.grab_set()
    root_admin.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", root.destroy)






root = Tk()

root.geometry('600x200')

root.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')

name = StringVar()
passw = StringVar()

l0 = Label(root,text="Введите имя пользователя",font=("Segoe UI", 18))
l0.pack()
name_entry = Entry(root,textvariable=name,width=30,font=("Arial", 30, "bold"))
name_entry.pack()
name_entry.focus_set()
but = Button(root,text="Войти",font=("Arial", 18), command=clicked)
but.pack()

root.mainloop()
```